# Cxvpy-ECOS solver runs forever

Tags: python, cvxpy, convex-optimization

I'm having a maximisation problem with linear constraints.
The CVXPY is using ECOS solver. The optimisation algorithm worked for medium sized data, but for large data the algorithm runs forever.

The problem goes like this,
I hold a courier service, I ship packages from one place to other place. For 'N' packages I ship from a place 'A' to place 'B' I get income 'K' and it takes time 'T'. I want to stop shipping from some location 'X' to location 'Y', given if the time it takes to ship package is more than 2 days. At the same time I might prefer holding that route if it generates me more income even if it's more than 2 days.

```
selection = cvxpy.Variable(len(K), boolean=True)
constraints = [((T - 2)*N)*selection <= 0]
income = K*selection
problem = cvxpy.Problem(cvxpy.Maximize(income), constraints)
```

Based on the selection variable I choose if I should hold or stop shipping for that route.

Turning on the verbose, there are logs of iterations and I also get to see comments like Optimal, Close to Optimal, Maximum iterations reached but algorithm continues to run.

I'm new to these solvers. Where do I start debugging this problem?

Also I would like to understand what feastol, reltol, abstol mean and how number of iterations effect the solver?

Comment: You did not show any code. If i had to guess: you are optimizing over discrete sets (binary or integer variables). Well... ECOS_BB is a toy-solver then (and the general problem is np-hard anyway). As written, this question is too broad! We simply don't know what exactly you are doing.

Comment: Added problem details and sample code. Can I get basic idea of what the parameters mean and how they effect the solver?

Comment: I suggest you give MOSEK a try.